# Can we describe all the page names in salesforce

Tags: apex, describesobject

We need to get all custom page names into the select box. Is there any way that we can describe all pages like objects

Answer (score 11):

You can query for apex pages, returning a list of `selectOption` instances as you would for any other custom list:

```
// controller
public String chosen {get; set;}

public List<SelectOption> GetPageOptions()
{
  List<SelectOption> pages = new List<SelectOption>();

  for(ApexPage p : [select Id, Name from ApexPage limit 1000])
  {
    // use the ID as a value, the page name as a label
    pages.add(new SelectOption(p.Id, p.Name));
  }

  return pages;
}

// page
<apex:selectList value="{!chosen}">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!PageOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```